# Using better-sqlite3 how would you run EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN (programatically)

Tags: sql-execution-plan, better-sqlite3

Should be a simple answer,
How can I execute an EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN in JS using better-sqlite3.

I've tried:

```
db.prepare('EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN select * from users').all();
db.pragma('EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN select * from users');
etc...
```

but none are giving me the results.

Thanks

Ben